# cumulative probability of an event happening

Tags: probability

A production line is making 4 color (red, blue,green,yellow) gumballs and dropping 7 balls in a small bottle and 24 balls in a large bottle. Both bottles are sold as a pack.
All balls have equal probability and the production line is making a 10 thousand a day.

What is the probability that the smaller bottle has exactly one red ball, and the larger bottle has exactly 7 red balls.

Will the probability of smaller bottle be multiplied with larger bottle. How to calculate the cumulative probability ? Any ideas anyone please.

Comment: It is not perfectly clear in what fashion the color of the balls is determined, so there is not enough information to continue.  The answer could be anything from $0$ to $1$.  If we were to assume that each gumball has it's color uniformly and independently selected at random, then this becomes two binomial probability questions.  The second of which for example being "What is the probability of flipping exactly seven heads out of twentyfour flips of a biased coin, where the coin has probability of heads on each flip as $1/4$?"

Comment: The machine randomly fills the bottles. The small bottle has 7 gum balls and the larger bottle has 24 balls. The machine is making 10 thousand gum balls a day and all 4 color gum balls are produced in equal number, therefore the gum balls have equal probability.

Comment: @AngelinaBroccoli: I think many of us would say that only the first gumball is sure to have equal probability to be each of the four colors: $1/4$.  Once that gumball is in the bottle, then whatever color it is (let's say it's green) has its probability drop to $2499/9999$ for the second gumball, while the other three colors—red, blue, and yellow—go up to $2500/9999$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is it, there are some ambiguities, or at least some issues to make more precise.

We need to assume that:

- Every color has the same probability on each pick.
- Every pick is independent of the previous ones (which is reasonable if we have a large quantity of gumballs, much more than 7 and 24).
- Large and small bottles are filled in a way that the content of one is independent of the others (for instance, one is filled after the other; or there are different machines for each type; etc.).

Under those circumstances, if we call $R_S$ and $R_L$ to the number of red balls in the small and the large bottle, respectively, then:

- Yes, independence between bottles imply 
  $$P(R_S=1 \wedge R_L=7)=P(R_S=1) \cdot P(R_L=7).$$
- Every time you pick a ball, the probability that it be red is $\tfrac14$.
- When you pick the balls for the small bottle you are repeating 7 times the same random experience, and everytime the probability that the ball be red is the same... so what do you think is the distribution of $R_S$?
- And what about $R_L$?

(The answer, at the end).

If you know that, then is easy to do the calculations since, as we said, we want
$$P(R_S=1 \wedge R_L=7) = P(R_S=1) \cdot P(R_L=7).$$

But I don't quite get to which random variable you refer when you ask for the cumulative distribution. $R_S$? $R_L$? Their sum? Something else?

---

ANSWER: It's clear that
$$R_S \sim Bin(7,0.25) \quad \text{and} \quad R_L \sim Bin(24,0.25).$$

---

---

UPDATE:
That probability (the 1,7 combination) is the number you get in the previous calculations. Let's call that result $P(R_S=1 \wedge R_L=7):=p_*$.

Then, to discuss how many times will that haven among $n$ packs, has nothing to do with cumulative probabilities of the variables we've been defining. Now you are repeating $n$ independent times (n=1000, 5000, etc.) an experiment (preparing a pack and checking if it has the desired number of red balls); so the number of "successful" packages (say $X$) among $n$ is again a binomial r.v., now $X \sim Bin(n,p_*)$.

You can answer now any question about $X$. In particular, if you want the expected number of "successful" packages, remember that since it is a binomial distribution you will have $E(X)=np_*$ (and $Var(X)=np_*(1-p_*)$, in case you're wondering). And also remember that for 'large' $n$ you can answer questions about $X$ using an approximation with the normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want the total probability of the pack (i.e two bottles) such that the small bottle has 1 red and larger bottle has 7 red balls. I want to predict if 1000,5000,10,000 packs are produced how many packs will have this combination of 1 and 7.

Comment: Ok, I've added that in the UPDATE section.

Comment: This is very helpful. I was able to calculate Bin(7,0.25) as 0.311 and Bin(24,0.25) as 0.158. How to ^ them ? to get the combined probability so that the small bottle must have 1 red among 7 balls and large bottle must have 7 red among 24 balls.

Comment: Independence implies that you just have to multiply both. It's in the answer, but I guess the formula was displayed in two lines. I think I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you, Got the correct answer.